# How do I make mpv pause streaming audio files when disconnected?

Tags: command-line, streaming, mpv-media-player

So, I've been using the awesome mpv media player for my primary compressed audio player, lately (it does an excellent job for that on the command-line as long as the video is disabled).

Imagine I have an m3u playlist of URLs (from the Internet) for mp3 files of a public domain LibriVox audiobook that I'm listening to (not all in one sitting), and I'm playing that playlist from the command-line with this:

`mpv --no-video --save-position-on-quit playlist.m3u`

Currently, if I have an Internet connection, it plays just fine. However, if the connection drops, it skips all the files until the end of the playlist and stops, therefore making me lose my place in the audiobook that I'm listening to. What I want it to do instead is pause, or stop, instead of proceeding to the next track, while remembering where I was before my connection was lost. How do I accomplish this, short of downloading the mp3 files in advance (imagine my device has limited memory, and I don't want to use it up with these mp3 files, if I can help it)?

While this is no longer an urgent problem, since I've switched to a device with more memory, and can download stuff in advance, I'm still curious about the answer.

It's really saving the position before the connection was lost that I care about here, and resuming it when it's back.

Comment: why do use mpv (which is a **video**player)?  mpg123 should work.

Comment: While mpv is a videoplayer, it's not a one trick pony. It's an extremely good music player, even compared to high-profile GUI-based ones that specialize in audio (that is, if you use the --no-video tag; if you let mpv's GUI for videos load, you won't see how it shines as a music player). It's very fast, let's you use keyboard shortcuts, lets you repeat, repeat 1, shuffle, lets you play specific files (without having to deal with a searchable library), lets you fast forward and rewind really nicely with the arrow keys, effectively streams audio you haven't downloaded first; it's programmable.

Comment: You can do lots of other stuff, too. However, I'm not averse to hearing how you can do the desired stuff in other command-line players (although I probably wouldn't accept it as the answer unless it addressed the mpv situation directly, too).

Comment: I'm using mpv im my [Videocut](https://github.com/kanehekili/VideoCut) app, so I am very aware of its capabilities. I'll check if I can find something... (they have so many switches ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

mpv describes the follwing option:

`--loop-playlist=force`

```
The force mode is like inf, but does not skip playlist entries 
which have been marked as failing. 
This means the player might waste CPU time trying to loop a file that doesn't exist. 
But it might be useful for playing webradios under very bad network conditions.
```

Whereas the option: `--save-position-on-quit` works only, if you **quit** the app. It states explicitly:

```
This does not happen if playback of a file is stopped in any other way than quitting.
```

(which is what you described)

The switches and flags are documented on [this page](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#watch-later)

Comment: Hmm. That's very interesting. However, with `--loop-playlist=force` enabled, if I get disconnected from the Internet, it still advances from unavilable track to unavailable track (albeit, not nearly as quickly; maybe you need a special kind of playlist for that to work). It still saves the position if I quit with Ctrl+c instead of q (although if I suspend it with Ctrl+z, it not only doesn't save it, it forgets everything it saved, unless I do `fg` to continue it, as opposed to starting it again). Maybe I could make a Lua script that will make it pause if the Internet gets disconnected.